# How to display an alternative text if the comments are closed for the node?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, comments

in my node type template, how do I display alternate text if comments are closed for the node ?

```
  {% if content.comment %}
    <div class="card mb-5 p-3 shadow">
      {{ content.comment }}
    </div>
  {% else %}
    <div class="card mb-5 p-3 shadow">
      {{ content.field_link }}
      {{ content.field_code }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

EXAMPLE

> If comments are open :
>
> {{ content.comment }}
>
> If comments are closed :
>
> TEXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default field definitions installed by the standard profile, what you want is the `status` property of the `comment` field of the node, which is accessible in twig via `node.comment.status`.

```
{% if node.comment.status == 2 %}
   {# comments are open #}
{% elseif node.comment.status == 1 %}
   {# comments are closed & visible #}
{% elseif node.comment.status == 0 %}
   {# comments are closed & hidden #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks it works